# Python smtplib email doesn't send to External Addresses

Tags: python-2.7, smtp, smtplib, mime-mail

I'm able to automate some emails internally using mime and smtplib, but for some reason, these emails fail to send to external addresses (outside of company's domain)

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email import Encoders
import smtplib

SERVER = 'mailrelay'
FROM = 'myemail@internaldomain.com'
TO = ['myemail@internaldomain.com','someemail@externaldomain.com']

body = 'This is a test'

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg["To"] = ','.join(TO)
msg["From"] = FROM
msg["Subject"] = 'Automated Test Email'

msgText = MIMEText(body, 'html')
msg.attach(msgText)

message = msg.as_string()

server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
server.sendmail(FROM,TO,message)
server.quit()
```

Produces this error:

```
SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'someemail@externaldomain.com': (550, '5.7.1 Unable to relay')}
```

Admin insists that relaying is enabled, and told me that sending emails to external domains using Powershell works, so it can't be a relay issue.

So now I'm stuck. If it's not the problem python is telling me it is, is my admin wrong or is something else going on?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I just needed to authenticate in this case:

```
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo
server.login('user', 'pass')
```